# C# How can I compare objects' attributes that are elements of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, compare

I have created a class named Card and a class named CardDeck.
In class CardDeck I've declared an array named deck( of type Card ) whose elements are objects of class Card.
Its Card object has its own number and shape.

How can I compare for example deck[0] with deck[1] to see if these obects have the same number or the same shape?

Class CardDeck

```
using System;
public Class CardDeck
{ 
   private int number_of_elements = 30;
   public CardDeck()//constructor
   {
      int[] arrayNumber = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
      string[] arrayShape = { "oval" , "diamond", "square" };
      deck = new Card[number_of elements];
      InitialiseDeck(arrauNumber, arrayShape);
   }
   private void InitialiseDeck(int[] num, string[] sha)
   {
      int count = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         {
            deck[count] = new Card(num[i],sha[j]);
            count++;
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Class Card

```
using System;
public class Card
{
   private int number;
   private string shape;

   public Card( int cardNumber, string cardShape)
   {
      number = cardNumber;
      shape = cardShape;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make public attributes on the `Card` class that expose the `number` and `shape` variables. Then in code outside the `Card` class reference those attributes.

For example:

```
public class Card
{
   private int number;
   private string shape;

   public Card( int cardNumber, string cardShape)
   {
      number = cardNumber;
      shape = cardShape;
   }
   public int Number { get { return this.number; } }
   public string Shape { get { return this.shape; } }
}
```

Usage:

```
var card1 = new Card(13, "diamond");
var card2 = new Card(13, "heart");
if (card1.Number == card2.Number && card2.Shape == card2.Shape)
{
    // The cards are the same
}
```

If all you want to do is check for equality of cards, then you can just declare what the `==` operator will do for the `Card` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx

Comment: Thank you! But after that how will I compare let's say attribute number of object Deck[0] with attribute number of Deck[1] to see if thay have the same number?@Matt Thomas

Comment: @Peridis Would you be able to use Deck[0].Number == Deck[1].Number?

Comment: @Peridis Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow!